# JavaScript replace works in console, but not on the website

Tags: javascript, replace, console.log

I've been trying to create a list of tags and separate them using commas. I'm using Webflow and sadly it's not possible in their cms.

I thought of a workaround where I would replace the commas with code using JavaScript.

Here's the code:

```
function tags() {
  var tag = document.getElementById("tag__wrap").innerHTML;
  str = tag.replace(/,/g, '</p><p class="tag__wrap">');
}

tags();
console.log(str);
```

For some reason the code works fine when I look it up in the console, but doesn't actually show anything on the actual website.
Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're wanting to display tag after replacing the ',' or str value. Either way you need to return tag or str in your tag function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create multiple elements in place of the single element (that has the comma separated tags), then you need to manipulate the DOM. It is not enough to assign HTML to a string variable.

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:

```js
function tags() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tag__wrap");
  var tags = elem.textContent.match(/[^,\s]+/g) || [];
  elem.textContent = tags.shift();
  for (let text of tags) {
      var newElem = elem.cloneNode();
      newElem.textContent = text;
      elem.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newElem);
      elem = newElem;
  }
}

// Delay the change, so you can see before & after in the snippet
setTimeout(tags, 1000);
```

```css
#tag__wrap { 
   background: lightblue;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 3px 8px;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p id="tag__wrap">algorithm,javascript,html,css</p>
```